# Take a picture from camera, compress it and store in location which i specific

Tags: android, image, path, image-compression

I want to take a picture using the camera and compress it and store it in the path I created.
What I have done right now is clicking the picture and store the original picture in my path but I want to compress it before storing it so I can retrieve the path of the compressed image.

To save the original image I have created my own path and it is stored in the variable *mCurrentPhotoPath*.

The main thing is I want the path it is stored.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
package com.howaboutthis.satyaraj.videntify;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class IdentifyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 200;
    private static final int CLICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 2;
    private static final String TAG = "IdentifyActivity";
    private RequestPermissionHandler mRequestPermissionHandler;

    String mCurrentPhotoPath;

    String userName;
    String userEmail;
    Uri profileURL;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_identify);

        mRequestPermissionHandler = new RequestPermissionHandler();

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        assert bundle != null;
        userName = bundle.getString("username");

        Button cameraButton = findViewById(R.id.camera);
        Button galleryButton = findViewById(R.id.gallery);

        cameraButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        galleryButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_profile) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(IdentifyActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("username", userName);

            intent.putExtra("user_email", userEmail);
            intent.putExtra("profile_url",profileURL);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if (id == R.id.action_about)
            return true;

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.camera:
                takePicture();
                break;

            case R.id.gallery:
                pickFromGallery();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void pickFromGallery() {

        String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA};

        mRequestPermissionHandler.requestPermission(this, PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO, new RequestPermissionHandler.RequestPermissionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailed() {
                Toast.makeText(IdentifyActivity.this, "Request permission failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    private void takePicture() {

        String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

        mRequestPermissionHandler.requestPermission(this, PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO, new RequestPermissionHandler.RequestPermissionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailed() {
                Toast.makeText(IdentifyActivity.this, "Request permission failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

            Uri uri = data.getData();

            File finalFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(uri));
            Intent intent = new Intent(IdentifyActivity.this, detailedActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("PATH", finalFile.getPath());
            startActivity(intent);

        } else if (requestCode == CLICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            galleryAddPic();

            Intent intent = new Intent(IdentifyActivity.this, detailedActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("PATH", mCurrentPhotoPath);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        mRequestPermissionHandler.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions,
                grantResults);
    }

    public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        String picturePath = null;
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
        }
        return picturePath;
    }

    //Creating a path for the captured image to be saved. Using this path we can retrieve the original Image.
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.e(TAG,"Error while creating the file");
                // Error occurred while creating the File
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "com.howaboutthis.satyaraj.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CLICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
            }
        }
    }

    // Adding the pic to the gallery so that it is visible to everyone
    private void galleryAddPic() {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by compress? Do you to compress a raw image to jpeg or do want to archives  it i.e zip?

Comment: @NizaSiwale No not archives, i want compress the raw image

Comment: I know one way to do it but don't know how to implement it. What i thought was after the original image is saved, then i get the original image  using the path i have and compress using bitmap.compress and store the compressed image back into the same path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply read load and save it

```
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
options.inSampleSize = 2;  //you can also calculate your inSampleSize
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    Bitmap bmp= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath, options);
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(photoPath);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); // bmp is your Bitmap instance
        // PNG is a lossless format, the compression factor (100) is ignored
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

If you want a really small image then you also have to change it's resolution

public String compressImage(String imagePath) {
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;

```
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);

    int actualHeight = options.outHeight;
    int actualWidth = options.outWidth;

    float imgRatio = (float) actualWidth / (float) actualHeight;
    float maxRatio = maxWidth / maxHeight;

    if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth) {
        if (imgRatio < maxRatio) {
            imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;
            actualWidth = (int) (imgRatio * actualWidth);
            actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
        } else if (imgRatio > maxRatio) {
            imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
            actualHeight = (int) (imgRatio * actualHeight);
            actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;
        } else {
            actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
            actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;

        }
    }

    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, actualWidth, actualHeight);
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    options.inDither = false;
    options.inPurgeable = true;
    options.inInputShareable = true;
    options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];

    try {
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();

    }
    try {
        scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(actualWidth, actualHeight, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }

    float ratioX = actualWidth / (float) options.outWidth;
    float ratioY = actualHeight / (float) options.outHeight;
    float middleX = actualWidth / 2.0f;
    float middleY = actualHeight / 2.0f;

    Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
    scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
    canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, middleX - bmp.getWidth() / 2, middleY - bmp.getHeight() / 2, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

    if(bmp!=null)
    {
        bmp.recycle();
    }

    ExifInterface exif;
    try {
        exif = new ExifInterface(imagePath);
        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        if (orientation == 6) {
            matrix.postRotate(90);
        } else if (orientation == 3) {
            matrix.postRotate(180);
        } else if (orientation == 8) {
            matrix.postRotate(270);
        }
        scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0, scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    String filepath = getFilename();
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(filepath);

       //write the compressed bitmap at the destination specified by filename.
        scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return filepath;
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
    }
    final float totalPixels = width * height;
    final float totalReqPixelsCap = reqWidth * reqHeight * 2;

    while (totalPixels / (inSampleSize * inSampleSize) > totalReqPixelsCap) {
        inSampleSize++;
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Comment: after compression in your way, i sent the path to the url i had to process the image, it gave me an error saying _Failed to allocate a 96132148 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 72MB until OOM_

Comment: the size is still large it about 5mb, i want it to be in kbs like whatsapp images

Comment: You also have to change the resolution if you want a really small image. I've updated my solution